# R Converting a Dataframe to a labeled Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataframe with this data.

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   CpG, Group [20]
   CpG        Group  Range
   <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 cg01003813    1. 0.971 
 2 cg01003813    2. 0.0917
 3 cg01003813    3. 0.0535
 4 cg01003813    4. 0.0627
 5 cg01003813    5. 0.0575
 6 cg26484667    1. 0.0768
 7 cg26484667    2. 0.104 
 8 cg26484667    3. 0.0735
 9 cg26484667    4. 0.0453
10 cg26484667    5. 0.139 
11 cg25296477    1. 0.0745
12 cg25296477    2. 0.130 
13 cg25296477    3. 0.0772
14 cg25296477    4. 0.131 
15 cg25296477    5. 0.0765
16 cg13176022    1. 0.0895
17 cg13176022    2. 0.0236
18 cg13176022    3. 0.0412
19 cg13176022    4. 0.0478
20 cg13176022    5. 0.0346
```

Then I spread the dataframe so that it looks how I would want the matrix to look:

```
> tidyr::spread(test, Group, Range, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   CpG [4]
  CpG           `1`    `2`    `3`    `4`    `5`
  <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 cg01003813 0.971  0.0917 0.0535 0.0627 0.0575
2 cg13176022 0.0895 0.0236 0.0412 0.0478 0.0346
3 cg25296477 0.0745 0.130  0.0772 0.131  0.0765
4 cg26484667 0.0768 0.104  0.0735 0.0453 0.1390
```

Now I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to turn this into a properly formatted and labeled matrix.

I want my 5 groups as the column headers (like they are). I want the CpGs as row names (currently they are the first column. 
I just can't figure out how to make this into a properly labeled matrix.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Take a look at the reshape2 or tidyr packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just turn it into a matrix like below

```
m <- tidyr::spread(test, Group, Range, fill = 0)
mat <- as.matrix(m[, -1])
dimnames(mat) <- list(m$CpG, colnames(m[, -1]))
mat

                1      2      3      4      5
cg01003813 0.9710 0.0917 0.0535 0.0627 0.0575
cg13176022 0.0895 0.0236 0.0412 0.0478 0.0346
cg25296477 0.0745 0.1300 0.0772 0.1310 0.0765
cg26484667 0.0768 0.1040 0.0735 0.0453 0.1390
```

Answer (score 1):

`xtabs` gets you closer to what you want:

```
set.seed(1)
(foo <- cbind(expand.grid(CpG=letters[1:4], Group=1:5), Range = runif(20)))
#>    CpG Group      Range
#> 1    a     1 0.26550866
#> 2    b     1 0.37212390
#> 3    c     1 0.57285336
#> 4    d     1 0.90820779
#> 5    a     2 0.20168193
#> 6    b     2 0.89838968
#> 7    c     2 0.94467527
#> 8    d     2 0.66079779
#> 9    a     3 0.62911404
#> 10   b     3 0.06178627
#> 11   c     3 0.20597457
#> 12   d     3 0.17655675
#> 13   a     4 0.68702285
#> 14   b     4 0.38410372
#> 15   c     4 0.76984142
#> 16   d     4 0.49769924
#> 17   a     5 0.71761851
#> 18   b     5 0.99190609
#> 19   c     5 0.38003518
#> 20   d     5 0.77744522

xtabs(Range ~ Group + CpG, foo)
#>      CpG
#> Group          a          b          c          d
#>     1 0.26550866 0.37212390 0.57285336 0.90820779
#>     2 0.20168193 0.89838968 0.94467527 0.66079779
#>     3 0.62911404 0.06178627 0.20597457 0.17655675
#>     4 0.68702285 0.38410372 0.76984142 0.49769924
#>     5 0.71761851 0.99190609 0.38003518 0.77744522
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this exact function, however there appears to be a problem with my dataframe where I still have columns left over from before I called dplyr::distinct. I will have to look into this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Got it. I needed to run droplevels() on the dataframe first.